# What is the use of Maximum cached response size in IIS

Tags: iis

Currently for our application we have set Maximum reponse size as 512KB.
WHat is the use of this? We have configured to cache js and css files. 
But there are multiple js files having size more than 400KB. So does this mean that the cache of IIS is not being used.